# Indexing Wikipedia dump to elasticsearch gets XML document structures must start and end within the same entity error

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, wikipedia

I want to index wikipedia to elasticsearch.

I tried stream2es + elasticsearch 2.0.0
and Wikipedia River Plugin 2.6.0 + elasticsearch 1.6.0
to index latest wikipedia dump https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20151102/enwiki-20151102-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2.

However both got the same error message:

```
XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure how to make the XML imports work, but there is another option. Recently wikimedia has made available dumps of the production elasticsearch indices.

The indices are exported every week and for each wiki there are two exports.

- The content index, which contains only article pages:
  http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/cirrussearch/20151116/enwiki-20151116-cirrussearch-content.json.gz
- The general index, containing all pages. This includes talk pages, templates, etc: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/cirrussearch/20151116/enwiki-20151116-cirrussearch-general.json.gz

These are formatted for the elasticsearch bulk import API. Because that is JSON these are also usable outside elasticsearch.

Importing them is not documented yet, but i do roughly the following:

1. Fetch the current mapping: `curl https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump&format=json > mapping.json`
2. Feed that mapping into elasticsearch: `jq .content < mapping.json | curl -XPUT localhost:9200/enwiki_content --data @-`
3. Load the dump: `zcat enwiki-20151116-cirrussearch-general.json.gz | parallel --pipe -L 2 -N 2000 -j3 'curl -s http://localhost:9200/enwiki_content/_bulk --data-binary @- > /dev/null'`

Comment: Thanks for this post. Can you point me to some interesting queries those I can run against "content" index?

Comment: Any examples of some queries? How can I get "Mark_Twain"?

Comment: @kristen you can have a look at how the queries are generated on wikipedia by adding '&cirrusDumpQuery' to the URL e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&profile=default&fulltext=Search&search=mark+twain&cirrusDumpQuery . If you're looking for simple lookup queries then a simple term query on the all_near_match field should be OK.

Comment: @nomoa is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @kristen unfortunately I'm not aware of any docs that explain the low level details of the wikipedia indices. There are few debug params available that may help you to have a better understanding: dump a single document : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Twain?action=cirrusDump, mapping: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-mapping-dump and analyzer settings: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=cirrus-settings-dump. And this blog post: https://www.elastic.co/blog/loading-wikipedia .